# Exclude folders from Net Beans 8 PHP code analysis

Tags: php, code-analysis, netbeans-8

I've been using Net Beans 8 for PHP development at work for the past year or so, and found (Since updating to 8.0 and generating new projects) that the code analyzer detects errors in some of the free libraries we use, which in turn causes the project to be marked as having errors (Red exclamation mark on the Projects browser).

Since we do not mantain these libraries, I added them to the **Project Properties -> Ignored Folders -> Extra Folders for Code Analysis** settings of my current project (I don't want to exclude them from the project, since we use the autocomplete/intellisense feature of the IDE), but this had no visible effect: The files are still marked as having an error, as well as the project.

Am I using the code analyzer exclusions feature wrongly? Is there any way to have the selected folders excluded from error checking but still have them visible within the project?

Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for too

Comment: I wonder if "code analysis" in this case just pertains to the inclusion in the on-the-fly lookup of variables, selectors, etc., rather than the analysis of the file itself.

Comment: I meant specifically error and warning checking, since I was using the variables and types lookup, but so far I have not been able to find a way to disable one without the other...

Comment: "Extra Folders for Code Analysis" is exactly opposite of what you (and me) need - it adds folders from the outside of the project (such as global Composer's packages) to be available in code completion. I would like to exclude `vendor` dir, because there are some tests with syntax errors (for example) and NetBeans marks projects as containing errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work when you add the folder to both boxes. The folders won't display in the project folder list, no errors are being displayed. But the autocomplete still shows all (in my case "WordPress") library functions stored in these folders.

[image: Project folder settings]

Comment: I've actually moved on from NetBeans (most of my work nowadays is nodejs and I use VS Code), but I booted my old NB again and this works like a charm. I hope someone finds this useful!

Comment: I tried in NetBeans 20 and it did not work for me